# How to get totals per day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I have a table that looks like the following:

```
                  Table Name: Emails
    ID        |CreatedDate             |finalStatus
    115173922 |2013-04-09 12:33:23.234 |DELIVERED
    115123432 |2013-04-09 08:21:23.234 |FAILED
    115143212 |2013-04-09 12:24:23.234 |DELIVERED
    115173922 |2013-04-09 05:05:23.234 |DELIVERED
    111233922 |2013-04-10 12:44:23.234 |PENDING
    115123912 |2013-04-10 12:05:23.234 |DELIVERED
    115173922 |2013-04-11 22:09:23.234 |DELIVERED
    111233922 |2013-04-11 13:05:23.234 |PENDING
    115123912 |2013-04-11 05:23:23.234 |DELIVERED
```

What I need to do is get the total amount of DELIVERED, FAILED and PENDING finalStatus's per day for the month. I have tried to modify MySQL code that people have given in previous answers such as this: [SQL query for Calculating Total No. of Orders per Day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133109/sql-query-for-calculating-total-no-of-orders-per-day) but have not been able to get it working.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  (CAST(CreatedDate as DATE)) as Date,

    (SELECT COUNT(finalStatus)
    FROM [Emails]
    WHERE finalStatus = 'DELIVERED') AS Delivered,

    (SELECT COUNT(finalStatus)
    FROM [Emails]
    WHERE finalStatus = 'FAILED') AS Failed,

    (SELECT COUNT(finalStatus)
    FROM [Emails]
    WHERE finalStatus = 'PENDING') AS Pending

    FROM [Emails]
    GROUP BY (CAST(CreatedDate as DATE))
```

If anyone could help me that would be amazing. I have been stuck on this for a few hours now and may go crazy soon...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943968/help-with-multiple-group-by-sql-server-query

group by year than group by month..

Comment: do you still want to show the date even if it has no transaction on that day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is `SQL Server 2008`, make use of casting the `CREATEDDATE` into `DATE` only using `CAST()`,

```
SELECT CAST(E.CreatedDate AS DATE) DateCreated,
       COUNT(case when E.finalStatus = 'DELIVERED' then 1 end) as DELIVERED,
       COUNT(case when E.finalStatus = 'FAILED' then 1 end) as FAILED,
       COUNT(case when E.finalStatus = 'PENDING' then 1 end) as PENDING
FROM    TableName E
GROUP   BY CAST(E.CreatedDate AS DATE)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc195/4

Comment: Thanks soo much. I have been looking for this for a while but I just could not seem to find any answers that I could convert to my exact situation. There are lots which do this without the where clause (joining simple select statements) but non helped. Thanks

Comment: There is perhaps a weakness in this approach; if it is possible that a new status ('RETURNED') might be possible in the future, then the query will have to be rewritten. You can include the status column in the `GROUP BY` clause to get round this.

Comment: Thats not possible as these values are static and are returned by a service provider. Thanks for the feedback. No need for the data to be flushed at the start of every month. I simply used that as an example so the question was easier to understand.

Comment: @HughJones don't judge it by saying a weakness approach unless proven wrong. What you are saying are assumptions that need to be proven.

Comment: @SkinnyPipes - I was very careful to say PERHAPS a weakness - I cannot say for sure because we do not know much about the OPs requirement.  In some circumstances it might be a distinct advantage that future statuses are ignored by the query.

Comment: @Skinnypipes - Also - I suspect you are taking my comment as a criticism of your answer, which it is not.  You copied some logic from the OPs original question which is perfectly valid.  However, there is a nuance which I think has been missed - namely that there is an opportunity to `GROUP BY` both the created day AND the final status.  To my eye this was potentially a simple missing piece in the OPs logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

**[DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)**

```
select CAST(CreatedDate as DATE),
       sum(case when E.finalStatus = 'DELIVERED' then 1 else 0 end) as DELIVERED,
       sum(case when E.finalStatus = 'FAILED' then 1 else 0 end) as FAILED,
       sum(case when E.finalStatus = 'PENDING' then 1 else 0 end) as PENDING
from Emails E
where DATENAME(MONTH,E.CreatedDate)='your month name'
group by CAST(E.CreatedDate as DATE)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecf4a/17)**

Comment: OP wants ***per day for the month***, hence the **where**. None of the answer has taken that into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You can differ each month like this:

```
SELECT year(datestart), month(datestart)
finalStatus,
COUNT(finalStatus)
FROM [Emails]
GROUP BY year(datestart), month(datestart),finalStatus
```

And grouping like this is a much faster way, than subquerying.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but its not exactly what I was looking for I dont want to have to specify anything. As it should run by itself each month without extra input from me.

Comment: That is just a matter of supplying the correct parameter each month.  That can easily be automated with date arithmetic.  Rudy's answer is a good one you should think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT  (CAST(CreatedDate as DATE)) as Date,

    (SELECT COUNT(finalStatus)
    FROM [Emails] E1
    WHERE finalStatus = 'DELIVERED'  AND 
    CAST(E1.CreatedDate as DATE) = CAST(E.CreatedDate as DATE)) AS Delivered,

    (SELECT COUNT(finalStatus)
    FROM [Emails] E2
    WHERE finalStatus = 'FAILED' AND 
     CAST(E2.CreatedDate as DATE) = CAST(E.CreatedDate as DATE)) AS Failed,

    (SELECT COUNT(finalStatus)
    FROM [Emails] E3
    WHERE finalStatus = 'PENDING' AND 
     CAST(E3.CreatedDate as DATE) = CAST(E.CreatedDate as DATE)) AS Pending

    FROM [Emails] E
    GROUP BY (CAST(CreatedDate as DATE))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked although I am using Luv's one as it is a lot shorter. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with daily_figures as
(
select 
 cast(CreatedDate as date) as CreatedDate,
 finalStatus,
 Count(*) as DayCount
From 
  EMails
Group 
  by cast(CreatedDate as date), FinalStatus
)
select * from daily_figures 
Where 
  datepart(month, CreatedDate) = 4 and
  datepart(year, CreatedDate) = 2013
```

It depends on the circumstances of your application how you supply the necessary year.

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e07d1/8)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get the dates that has a transaction, *disregard this answer since both `LUV` and `Skinny Pipes`  has  already demonstrated it*.

Considering that you want to get all dates for the whole month of `APRIL`, you need first to generate a calendar table for the whole month of `APRIL` and then joined it with you table. This query uses recursive CTE to create a calendar.

```
WITH April_Calendar
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('20130401' as datetime) AS [date]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
  FROM   April_Calendar
  WHERE  DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '20130430'
)
SELECT  a.[Date] DateCreated,
        COUNT(case when E.finalStatus = 'DELIVERED' then 1 end) as DELIVERED,
        COUNT(case when E.finalStatus = 'FAILED' then 1 end) as FAILED,
        COUNT(case when E.finalStatus = 'PENDING' then 1 end) as PENDING
FROM    April_Calendar a
        LEFT JOIN Emails E
            ON a.[date] = CAST(E.CreatedDate AS DATE)
GROUP   BY a.[Date]
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecf4a/21)