# MSSQL Totals per day for a month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to do something very similar to a question I have asked before but I cant seem to get it to work correctly. Here is my previous question: [How to get totals per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16013175/how-to-get-totals-per-day)

the table looks as follows:

```
              Table Name: Totals
Date       |Program label   |count
           |                |    
2013-04-09 |Salary Day      |4364
2013-04-09 |Monthly         |6231
2013-04-09 |Policy          |3523
2013-04-09 |Worst Record    |1423
2013-04-10 |Salary Day      |9872
2013-04-10 |Monthly         |6543
2013-04-10 |Policy          |5324
2013-04-10 |Worst Record    |5432
2013-04-10 |Salary Day      |1245
2013-04-10 |Monthly         |6345
2013-04-10 |Policy          |5431
2013-04-10 |Worst Record    |5232
```

My question is: Using MSSQL 2008 - Is there a way for me to get the total counts per Program Label per day for the current month. As you can see sometimes it will run twice a day. I need to be able to account for this.

The output should look as follows:

```
Date      |Salary Day |Monthly |Policy |Worst Record
2013-04-9 |23456      |63241   |23521  |23524
2013-04-10|45321      |72535   |12435  |83612
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
select Date,
  sum(case when [Program label] = 'Salary Day' then count else 0 end) [Salary Day],
  sum(case when [Program label] = 'Monthly' then count else 0 end) [Monthly],
  sum(case when [Program label] = 'Policy' then  count else 0 end) [Policy],
  sum(case when [Program label] = 'Worst Record' then count else 0 end) [Worst Record]
from Totals Group by [Date];
```

Comment: I have used your answer as it is the simplest, for me, to understand even though I have had to edit it a lot. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) table operator like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM Totals AS t
PIVOT
(
   SUM(count)
   FOR [Program label] IN ([Salary Day], 
                           [Monthly], 
                           [Policy], 
                           [Worst Record])
) AS p;
```

See it in action:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cb2cb/2)

This will give you:

```
|       DATE | SALARY DAY | MONTHLY | POLICY | WORST RECORD |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| 2013-04-09 |       4364 |    6231 |   3523 |         1423 |
| 2013-04-10 |      11117 |   12888 |  10755 |        10664 |
```

Comment: Thanks. I have learned something new through this :) Really helpful answer. I have not chosen to use it as its not something I am completely comfortable with yet. Although I will definitely start testing this out with my future queries.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
    date
    , [Salary Day] = SUM(CASE when [Program label] = 'Salary Day' then COUNT end)
    , [Monthly] = SUM(CASE when [Program label] = 'Monthly' then COUNT end) 
    , [Policy] = SUM(CASE when [Program label] = 'Policy' then COUNT end) 
    , [Worst Record] = SUM(CASE when [Program label] = 'Worst Record' then COUNT end)  
FROM Totals
GROUP BY [Date];
```